# How does <=> in php 7 responsed in situations that check bool values?

Tags: php, php-7

Looking into php 7 on the way, but <=> confuses me.

Most of the time I use conditional operators, they are used in boolean situations (which <=> almost is, but not quite, being able to return -1 as well). (If X <=> Y). So I'm not sure what will happen in the following cases...

```
if ($x <=> $y) {
    // Do all the 1 things
} else {
    // Do all the 2 things
}
```

What can I expect if it's preceded by...

```
$x = 0; $y = 1;
```

or

```
$x = "Carrot"; $y = "Carrot Juice";
```

or

```
$x = "Carrot Juice"; $y = "Carrot";
```

or

```
$x = array(carrot, juice); $y = "carrot juice";
```

There's definitely enough cases about this that it's confusing me as to what it'll do.

Comment: If the situations treat both the -1 and the 0 potential results as false... then I don't really get what makes it anything different than >.

Comment: It seems to be useless in if statements, because it is same as `<>` there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Introduction

The [**spaceship operator**](http://php.net/language.operators.comparison) `<=>` is a *non-associative* binary operator with the same precedence as equality operators (`==`, `!=`, `===`, `!==`).

The purpost of this operator, is to allow for simpler three-way comparison between left-hand and right-hand operands.

---

#### Possible outcomes

The operator can produce any of the following results :

- `0` : when both operands are equal
- `-1` : when the left-hand operand is less than the right-hand operand
- `1` : when the left-hand operand is greater than the right-hand operand.

So, that means :

```
1 <=> 1; // output : 0
1 <=> 2; // output : -1
2 <=> 1; // output : 1
```

---

#### Practical application

A good practical application of using this operator would be in comparison type callbacks that are expected to return a zero, negative, or positive integer based on a three-way comparison between two values. The comparison function passed to [`usort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) is one such example.

Before PHP 7, you would write this :

```
$arr = [4,2,1,3];

usort($arr, function ($a, $b) {
    if ($a < $b) {
        return -1;
    } elseif ($a > $b) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
});
```

Since PHP 7, you can write this :

```
$arr = [4,2,1,3];

usort($arr, function ($a, $b) {
    return $a <=> $b;
});
```

Answer (score 7):

The spaceship operator (and other PHP 7 additions) is explained in plain language here:

https://blog.engineyard.com/2015/what-to-expect-php-7

It's mostly useful in the comparison function supplied to functions like `usort`.

```
// Pre PHP 7
function order_func($a, $b) {
    return ($a < $b) ? -1 : (($a > $b) ? 1 : 0);
}

// Post PHP 7
function order_func($a, $b) {
    return $a <=> $b;
}
```

It's not very useful in `if`, because `if` only checks whether the value is truthy or falsey, the different truthy values representing the ordering are not distinguished. If you do use it in a boolean context, it will be considered `true` when the values are different (because `1` and `-1` are bother truthy), `false` when they're equal (because `0` is falsey). This is similar to trying to use `strcmp()` and `stricmp()` in a boolean context, which is why you often see

```
if (stricmp($x, $y) == 0)
```

The rules for using arrays with comparison operators is given [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) (scroll down to the table labeled **Comparison with Various Types**). When comparing an array with another array, the rule is:

> Array with fewer members is smaller, if key from operand 1 is not found in operand 2 then arrays are uncomparable, otherwise - compare value by value

When comparing an array with another type, the array is always greater. So `array('carrot', 'juice') <=> 'carrot juice'` will be `1`.

Comment: Since you mentioned it only makes since with ordered arrays, I'm assuming it compares the elements of each array with the highest ordinal value?

Comment: Sorry, I said that wrong. I meant "types that have an ordering", i.e. types where the idea of one element being ranked higher or lower than another value exists. Numbers are ordered by their numeric values, strings are ordered lexicographically.

Comment: The whole point is that `$x <=> $y` has to return a value that indicates whether `$x` is higher, lower, or equal to `$y`. How would you do that if they were arrays?

Comment: The operator works on arrays, that much has been shown already. What actually makes a difference in results is less clear. However, if we don't know what it does fully, we can't take full advantage of it. I'm not asking this question for the point of fixing a bug, but for the purpose of learning functionality for future reference.

Comment: I was wrong when I said arrays aren't orderable. I found the documentation that explains how they're ordered, and added it to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just try it out for yourself and play around with that new spaceship you got?

[<kbd>**Demo**</kbd>](https://3v4l.org/22g80#v700alpha1)

Also if you are wondering how the comparison of the [spaceship operator](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.spaceship-op) works, see: http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php

---

But now if we want to go into  a bit more detail about your test data:

1. First case:

   ```
   //Test data
   $x = 0;
   $y = 1;
   ```

   ```
   //operator
   0 <=> 1 //0 is smaller than 1, so result: -1
   //-1 evaluates to TRUE in the if statement
   ```
2. Second case:

   ```
   //Test data
   $x = "Carrot";
   $y = "Carrot Juice";
   ```

   ```
   //operator
   "Carrot" <=> "Carrot Juice" //"Carrot" is smaller than "Carrot Juice", so result: -1
   //-1 evaluates to TRUE in the if statement
   ```
3. Third case:

   ```
   //Test data
   $x = "Carrot Juice";
   $y = "Carrot";
   ```

   ```
   //operator
   "Carrot Juice" <=> "Carrot" //"Carrot Juice" is bigger than "Carrot", so result: 1
   //1 evaluates to TRUE in the if statement
   ```
4. Fourth case:

   ```
   //Test data
   $x = array("carrot", "juice");
   $y = "carrot juice";
   ```

   ```
   //operator
   array("carrot", "juice") <=> "carrot juice" //array("carrot", "juice") is bigger than "carrot juice", so result: 1
   //1 evaluates to TRUE in the if statement
   ```

Comment: Hmm, so in comparing numerical values and expecting a bool result, it's pretty much identical to <> for anything that expects a boolean result. Definitely useful for other situations, but for boolean operations, not so much. 

Very interesting. Also interesting to note how the string comes in less than the array. I'll have to look into that and see if arrays are always bigger or if it varies by content (could be useful in quick'n'dirty type comparisons.)